# Accessing and using csv file from Cloud Storage in Cloud Run instance

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

I know how to download the file from cloud storage within the cloud run instance. But, I can't find the syntax for reading the file in python. I'm looking to immediately convert the csv file into a pandas dataframe, just by using `pd.read_csv('testing.csv')`. So my personal code looks like,
`download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, 'testing.csv')`. So shouldn't I be able to do `pd.read_csv('testing.csv')` within the cloud run instance? When doing it this way, I keep getting an internal server when loading the page. It seems like a simple question, but I haven't been able to find an example of it anywhere. Everything just downloads the file, I never see it used.

```
def download_blob(bucket_name, source_blob_name, destination_file_name):
    """Downloads a blob from the bucket."""
    # The ID of your GCS bucket
    # bucket_name = "your-bucket-name"

    # The ID of your GCS object
    # source_blob_name = "storage-object-name"

    # The path to which the file should be downloaded
    # destination_file_name = "local/path/to/file"

    storage_client = storage.Client()

    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)

    # Construct a client side representation of a blob.
    # Note `Bucket.blob` differs from `Bucket.get_blob` as it doesn't retrieve
    # any content from Google Cloud Storage. As we don't need additional data,
    # using `Bucket.blob` is preferred here.
    blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
    blob.download_to_filename(destination_file_name)

    print(
        "Downloaded storage object {} from bucket {} to local file {}.".format(
            source_blob_name, bucket_name, destination_file_name
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a filename such as **'testing.csv'** means write the file to the current directory. What is the current directory? Instead, specify an absolute path to a known directory location.

Download to the **/tmp/** directory, e.g. **'/tmp/testing.csv'**. Using file system space consumes memory as the file system is RAM-based. Make sure the Cloud Run instance has enough memory.

[Excerpt from Cloud Run Container Runtime Contact](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract):

The filesystem of your container is writable and is subject to the following behavior:

- This is an in-memory filesystem, so writing to it uses the container instance's memory.
- Data written to the filesystem does not persist when the container instance is stopped.

[Reference: Filesystem access](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#filesystem)

Answer (score 1):

`download_as_bytes` is the function you're looking for if you want to load it directly to memory.

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(source_blob_name)
data = blob.download_as_bytes()
pd.read_csv(StringIO(data))
```

https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.download_as_bytes

Pandas also supports reading directly from Google Cloud Storage. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

> Any valid string path is acceptable. The string could be a URL. Valid
> URL schemes include http, ftp, s3, **gs**, and file.

So something like "gs://bucket/file"

Comment: Wanna give you an upvote because I did end up using @John_Hanley 's answer for another file and in this case it answers my questions head on. However, I also used pandas directly reading from the GCS. Thanks for the help!